# Ajax error handling Django responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have an ajax call to a Django view method:

```
$("#formi").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData($('form').get(0));

            $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"{% url 'calculate' %}",
                 data: data,
                 processData: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',

                 success: function(data){
                     ...

                    },


                 error : function(xhr) {
                        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
                    }
            });
       });
```

Here i send a .txt via a form submitting to the views.py to calculate some stuff.

This is my method:

```
def calculate(request):

    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        if len(request.FILES) != 0:

            data = request.FILES['some_file']

            if '.txt' in data.name:

                ... calculate...

                return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
            else:
                raise Http404("No File uploaded")
        else:
            raise Http404("No File uploaded")
    else:
        raise Http404("No POST data was given.")
```

As you can see i have the `else` statements in case a- is not  an ajax call - b- there are no files in the request - and c- ".txt" is not in the name of the file

But none of this `else` statements are working. I think is because of the ajax `error` part but i cannot figure it out.

How can i display a Message, Django message or a javascript alert message if none of this requirements are fullfill. 
Maybe create via javascript a new div with the message.

The main problem of course is the validation no being done.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: In your JS error function, before you log xhr.satus, can you add "console.log('here');" and then let me know what all gets logged to the console when you send a bad request? Edit: Also, in your python code, can you add a print statement before raising each error and let me know if the print statements get printed onto the terminal when you send a bad request? Just for debugging purposes...

Comment: Ok. I will do that and let you know

Comment: Did you try using ```raise ValidationError('...errormessage...')```
instead?

Answer (score -1):

You can check error using `django print` or `django pdb` debugging. It is an easy method for finding errors:

Here is the documentation: [django-pdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pdb)